# seek(0) on Linux /proc/sys/* pseudo-files?

Tags: linux, procfs, collectd

Are there documented standards for the semantics of Linux `/proc/sys` file descriptors?

Is it proper to use `seek(0)` on them?

Here's a piece of code which seems to work fine for my tests:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from time import sleep
with open('/proc/sys/fs/file-nr','r') as f:
    while True:
        d = f.readline()
        print d.split()[0]
        f.seek(0)
        sleep(1)
```

This seems to work.  However, I'd like to know if that's the right way to do such things or if I should loop over `open()` ... `read()` ... `close()`

In this particular case I'll be using this with the [collectd](http://collectd.org/) Python plugin ... so this particular code would be running indefinitely in a daemon.  However, I'm interested in the answer for the general class of questions.

(Incidentally is there an "open files/inodes" module/plugin for `collectd`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is proper to use lseek(2) and fseek(3) on files on proc pseudo-file system. Calls which aren't appropriate will result and error, thus if python seek (calling presumably lseek/fseek underneath) works, it's appropriate.